# Repeated TCP DUP ACK of the same initial packets

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

I'm using Wireshark to analyze one of the TCP conversations in my packet capture and I have this sequence where the entire conversation between these two ports is made out of TCP DUP ACK for the same two initial packets. Additionally each server sends their packet in what seems very close to exactly one second apart. I initially thought that these may be misidentified keep-alive packets but I struggle to wrap my head exactly about Wireshark will identify them this way.

[image]